# Off-the-Shelf C++ Hex Dump Code

Tags: c++, logging, hex, hexdump

I work a lot with network and serial communications software, so it is often necessary for me to have code to display or log hex dumps of data packets.

Every time I do this, I write yet another hex-dump routine from scratch.  I'm about to do so again, but figured I'd ask here:  Is there any good free hex dump code for C++ out there somewhere?

Features I'd like:

- N bytes per line (where N is somehow configurable)
- optional ASCII/UTF8 dump alongside the hex
- configurable indentation, per-line prefixes, per-line suffixes, etc.
- minimal dependencies (ideally, I'd like the code to all be in a header file, or be a snippet I can just paste in)

**Edit:**  Clarification: I am looking for code that I can easily drop in to my own programs to write to stderr, stdout, log files, or other such output streams.  I'm not looking for a command-line hex dump utility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unix tool `xxd` is distributed as part of [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php), and according to http://www.vmunix.com/vim/util.html#xxd, the source for xxd is ftp://ftp.uni-erlangen.de:21/pub/utilities/etc/xxd-1.10.tar.gz. It was written in C and is about 721 lines. The only licensing information given for it is this:

```
* Distribute freely and credit me,
* make money and share with me,
* lose money and don't ask me.
```

The unix tool `hexdump` is available from http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/softeng/Aegis/hexdump.html. It was written in C and can be compiled from source. It's quite a bit bigger than xxd, and is distributed under the GPL.

Answer (score 48):

I often use this little snippet I've written long time ago. It's short and easy to add anywhere when debugging etc...

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hexdump(void *ptr, int buflen) {
  unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)ptr;
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<buflen; i+=16) {
    printf("%06x: ", i);
    for (j=0; j<16; j++) 
      if (i+j < buflen)
        printf("%02x ", buf[i+j]);
      else
        printf("   ");
    printf(" ");
    for (j=0; j<16; j++) 
      if (i+j < buflen)
        printf("%c", isprint(buf[i+j]) ? buf[i+j] : '.');
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect!  this rocks.  i am using a socket reader and i called the function with "hexdump(buffer, bytecount);" and it works like a charm!  thank you!

Comment: printf("%02x ", (unsigned)(buf[i+j]));

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone finds it useful...

I've found single function implementation for ascii/hex dumper [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7775991/how-to-get-hexdump-of-a-structure-data/7776146#7776146).

A C++ version based on the same answer with ANSI terminal colours can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/shreyasbharath/32a8092666303a916e24a81b18af146b).

More lightweight than xxd.

Answer (score 0):

Could you write your [own dissector](http://www.richardsharpe.com/ethereal-stuff.html#Writing%20a%20Dissector) for Wireshark?

Edit: written before the precision in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have seen [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) used as a hex editor, but I usually do the same thing you do.  I'm surprised there's not an "instant answer" for this question.  It's a very common need.

Answer (score 0):

[I used this](http://einaros.blogspot.com/2006/11/put-hex-on-that-dump.html) in one of my internal tools at work.

Answer (score -1):

[xxd](https://manpages.org/xxd) is the 'standard' hex dump util and looks like it should solve your problems

Comment: Your link is dead