# Print Hexadecimal Numbers Of a File At C And C++

Tags: c++, file-io, hex

I'm now developing a home project, but before I start, I need to know how can I print<sup>`cout`</sup> the content of a file(*.bin as example) in hexadecimal?

I like to learn, then a good tutorial is very nice too **;-)**

Remember that I need to develop this, without using external applications, because this home project is to learn more about hexadecimal manipulating on C++ and also a good practice of my knowledge.

Some other questions

- Is there any way to do this using C?
- How can I store this value into a variable?

*I already got the way in C++, but how to make it in C?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To print hex:

```
std::cout << std::hex << 123 << std::endl;
```

but yes, use the [od](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_%28Unix%29) tool **:-)**
A good file reading/writing tutorial is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/). You will have to read the file into a buffer then loop over each byte/word of the file.

Comment: You will have to read the file into a buffer then loop over each byte/word of the file.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [od](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_%28Unix%29) tool.

Comment: Or `hexdump(1)` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump).  I really like the output format of `hexdump -C`.

Answer (score 2):

Another good hexdump tool is [`xxd`](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html) which also can output to a `C` array.

Otherwise to have some source code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242/off-the-shelf-hex-dump-code)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

1. Input the data as `unsigned char`.
2. Print the data as [file offset]
   [byte1] ...[byte16] [printable
   character]

If the character is not printable, use '.'.  Check the `isprint` function.

Start your program by reading one byte at a time.  Get this working.

Afterwards, you can make it more efficient by:

1. using block reads into a buffer
2. using `unsigned int` and processing
   more than one byte at a time.

Here is a stencil to help you out:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int
main(int num_parameters, char * argument_list[])
{
  std::string    filename("my_program.cpp");
  std::ifstream  inp_file(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
  if (!inp_file)
  {
     std::cerr << "Error opening test file: " << filename << "\n";
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  unsigned char  inp_byte;
  while (inp_file >> inp_byte)
  {
    // *your code goes here*
  }
  inp_file.close();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have Visual Studio, you can open any file as binary data. You'll see its hex representation right away.