# Problem reading hexadecimal buffer from C socket

Tags: sockets, recv

I'm using the SDL_net sockets API to create a server and client. I can easily read a string buffer, but when I try to send hexadecimal data, recv gets the length, but I cannot seem to be a able to read the buffer contents.

```
IPaddress ip;
TCPsocket server,client;
int bufSize = 1024;
char message[bufSize];
int len;

server = SDLNet_TCP_Open(&ip);
client = SDLNet_TCP_Accept(server);
len = SDLNet_TCP_Recv(client,message,bufSize);
```

Here's a snippet. the buffer length "**len**" is set (i.e. message length) but I can't get to the data contents in the message buffer. Some sample *bind_transmitter* PDU data was sent by a random client to the server at that port. I can't read the PDU (SMPP).

Comment: Do you mean *binary data* (as opposed to *string representation* of the data)? Also when you say "recv gets the length", do you mean that you send the length of the data first? Showing some code would really help.

Comment: I mean hexadecimal bytes. "recv" returns the appropriate number of bytes read to be equal to the size of data sent, but the received buffer seems to be empty

Comment: There are no "hexadecimal" bytes. It's either *binary* or *text*. What do you mean by "can't get to the data contents"? Do you try printing it as a string? Assuming it's binary the first zero byte terminates the string. These might be basic questions, but it's not at all clear what you are doing.

Comment: What I'm trying to develop is a simple SMPP socket listener. The client sends PDU data coded in hexadecimal octets, and I want to receive the PDU at my end (i.e. Socket Listener) and decode it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first check what's going on on the wire with a sniffer like [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Check that the bytes sent conform to any [SMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_message_peer-to-peer_protocol) [PDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit). If that is OK, then dump the buffer read with `SDLNet_TCP_Recv()` using the [`hexdump(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/hexdump) and see if it matches.

Some notes on the code:

- I don't see `ip` initialized anywhere, but I'm guessing you just skipped that part when pasting the code.

  `int bufSize = 1024; char message[bufSize];` is only valid in [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). Assuming [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), always compile with at least `-Wall -pedantic` to catch all warnings.

  The buffer is on the stack, so if you pass it to any function up the call chain, the result is [**U**ndefined **B**ehavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I would also try reproducing this with plain [Berkeley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), which are not that much more difficult then SDL, but much more fun :)

Answer (score 1):

use this snippet in c++ for an unformatted dump of a hex stream, previously saved to a buffer

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void hexdumpunformatted(void *ptr, int buflen) {
  unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)ptr;
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<buflen; i++) {
    printf("%02x ", buf[i]);
    printf(" ");
  }
}
```

call with

```
hexadumpunformatted(buffer, bytecount);
```

adapted from epatel's excellent [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29865/1166727) (this one gives you a full formatted dump).

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as you this week. I have been testing a server/client combo for essentially sending text messages. I figured I would do it this way before moving to hex, just to test the waters so to speak.

But moving to binary was most definitely a pain. What worked best for me was a buffer like this.(Just for recv(ing), I used another buffer to combine all the recv(ed) pieces together)

```
unsigned char Buffer[data_size];
memset(Buffer, 0, data_size);
```

Doing it this way worked very well for my purposes, a single byte of ff would print out nicely

```
0xff
```

as opposed to only being a buffer of signed chars which would leave me with

```
0xffffffff
```

So in terms of minimizing code, it was nice not having to finagle any formatting.

The trick is that you also have to be transmitting in binary. You can't expect to send text and just look at it's binary form on the receiving end. It definitely takes some experimentation, but I was finally able to send a document from my client to server just now.