# how to get hexdump of a structure data

Tags: c, pointers, binary-data, fwrite, hexdump

```
 ....
 finalize(char *hdrs, sendip_data *headers[], int index,
                    sendip_data *data, sendip_data *pack)
 {

 ........
```

For debugging purposes I want a hex dump of the `data` and `pack` structures, which are of type `sendip_data`, a really complex structure. Actually they contain some binary information so I am not sure whether output of my project is correct or not. So for debugging purposes, I want to write the data into a file so that I can use hexdump as follows -

```
$hexdump -C file.txt
```

Also as this is a run time generation of a n/w packet so I am also not sure about the length of `data` and `pack` structure which I think `fread / fwrite` will require ..So please suggest me something.

Comment: Not sure where to start here.  sizeof(sendip_data) will give the size of that structure, but are you saying that it contains pointers to other data that you also want to be part of the output?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242/off-the-shelf-c-hex-dump-code

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The following code will give you a hex dump of arbitrary memory from within your code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Usage:
//     hexDump(desc, addr, len, perLine);
//         desc:    if non-NULL, printed as a description before hex dump.
//         addr:    the address to start dumping from.
//         len:     the number of bytes to dump.
//         perLine: number of bytes on each output line.

void hexDump (
    const char * desc,
    const void * addr,
    const int len,
    int perLine
) {
    // Silently ignore silly per-line values.

    if (perLine < 4 || perLine > 64) perLine = 16;

    int i;
    unsigned char buff[perLine+1];
    const unsigned char * pc = (const unsigned char *)addr;

    // Output description if given.

    if (desc != NULL) printf ("%s:\n", desc);

    // Length checks.

    if (len == 0) {
        printf("  ZERO LENGTH\n");
        return;
    }
    if (len < 0) {
        printf("  NEGATIVE LENGTH: %d\n", len);
        return;
    }

    // Process every byte in the data.

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        // Multiple of perLine means new or first line (with line offset).

        if ((i % perLine) == 0) {
            // Only print previous-line ASCII buffer for lines beyond first.

            if (i != 0) printf ("  %s\n", buff);

            // Output the offset of current line.

            printf ("  %04x ", i);
        }

        // Now the hex code for the specific character.

        printf (" %02x", pc[i]);

        // And buffer a printable ASCII character for later.

        if ((pc[i] < 0x20) || (pc[i] > 0x7e)) // isprint() may be better.
            buff[i % perLine] = '.';
        else
            buff[i % perLine] = pc[i];
        buff[(i % perLine) + 1] = '\0';
    }

    // Pad out last line if not exactly perLine characters.

    while ((i % perLine) != 0) {
        printf ("   ");
        i++;
    }

    // And print the final ASCII buffer.

    printf ("  %s\n", buff);
}

// Very simple test harness.

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char my_str[] = "a char string greater than 16 chars";
    hexDump ("my_str", &my_str, sizeof (my_str), 16);
    return 0;
}
```

You pass into `hexDump` a description, memory address, length, and how many bytes you want on each line.

It will output a hex dump (including character data) for examination. When you run it with the included `main`, the output is:

```
my_str:
  0000  61 20 63 68 61 72 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67 20 67 72  a char string gr
  0010  65 61 74 65 72 20 74 68 61 6e 20 31 36 20 63 68  eater than 16 ch
  0020  61 72 73 00                                      ars.
```

Comment: nice..really helpful :)

Comment: replace if ((pc[i] < 0x20) || (pc[i] > 0x7e))
with  if (!isprint(pc[i]))

Comment: thank you good spirit.. I like your function, and i shall include it in my creations...part of your thoughts live in me now...

Comment: The example in main looks wrong. The second parameter is `&my_str` and it should be `my_str`

Comment: @frakman1, in this case, it makes no difference. The resulting type is different (pointer to char as opposed to pointer to char array) but they're both treated identically here (coerced to `void*/char*` in the function) . I prefer the `&something` form since it is needed if you have a non-array type, for example: `int my_int; hexDump ("my_int", &my_int, sizeof (my_int));`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528318/how-come-an-arrays-address-is-equal-to-its-value-in-c for more detail.

Comment: C++ version with ANSI colours here -
 https://gist.github.com/shreyasbharath/32a8092666303a916e24a81b18af146b

Answer (score 8):

A hex dump for Android, should be suitable for other platforms as well.

`LOGD()`, same as `DLOG()`, plays the role of `printf()` because `printf()` does not work in Android. For platforms other than Android, you may `#define DLOG printf`.

*dlog.h:*

```
// Android logging
#include <android/log.h>
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define DLOG(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)
#define ELOG(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR  , "~~~~~~", __VA_ARGS__)

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void log_dump(const void*addr,int len,int linelen);
void log_dumpf(const char*fmt,const void*addr,int len,int linelen);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

*dump.cpp:*

```
#include <dlog.h>
//#include <alloca.h>

inline char hdigit(int n){return "0123456789abcdef"[n&0xf];};

#define LEN_LIMIT 8
#define SUBSTITUTE_CHAR '`'

static const char* dumpline(char*dest, int linelen, const char*src, const char*srcend)
{
    if(src>=srcend) {
        return 0;
    }
    int i;
    unsigned long s = (unsigned long)src;
    for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
        dest[i] = hdigit(s>>(28-i*4));
    }
    dest[8] = ' ';
    dest += 9;
    for(i=0; i<linelen/4 ; i++) {
        if(src+i<srcend) {
            dest[i*3] = hdigit(src[i]>>4);
            dest[i*3+1] = hdigit(src[i]);
            dest[i*3+2] = ' ';
            dest[linelen/4*3+i] = src[i] >= ' ' && src[i] < 0x7f ? src[i] : SUBSTITUTE_CHAR;
        }else{
            dest[i*3] = dest[i*3+1] = dest[i*3+2] = dest[linelen/4*3+i] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return src+i;
}

void log_dumpf(const char*fmt,const void*addr,int len,int linelen)
{
#if LEN_LIMIT
    if(len>linelen*LEN_LIMIT) {
        len=linelen*LEN_LIMIT;
    }
#endif
    linelen *= 4;
    static char _buf[4096];
    char*buf = _buf;//(char*)alloca(linelen+1); // alloca() causes the initialization to fail!!!!
    buf[linelen]=0;
    const char*start = (char*)addr;
    const char*cur = start;
    const char*end = start+len;
    while(!!(cur = dumpline(buf,linelen,cur,start+len))){DLOG(fmt,buf);}
}

void log_dump(const void*addr,int len,int linelen)
{
    log_dumpf("%s\n",addr,len,linelen);
}
```

Usage example:

```
log_dumpf("args: %s\n", &p, 0x20, 0x10);
```

Output:

````````
args: 61efadc4 00 3c 17 01 6d bc 59 61 02 00 00 00 80 ae ef 61 `<``m`Ya```````a
args: 61efadd4 00 3c 17 01 00 00 00 00 31 a5 59 61 80 ae ef 61 `<``````1`Ya```a
````````

**UPDATE:**
see [dump.cpp](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/jni/reDroid/dump.cpp) and [re_dump.h](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/blob/master/jni/re_dump.h) in [reDroid (github)](https://github.com/18446744073709551615/reDroid/tree/master/jni), it includes a recursive dump that checks if a pointer is valid.

Comment: It's nice there's an update but doesn't provide a lot of ease that there are no instructions in the repository and the linked files reference other files inside it.