# File transfer from Server to Client in C programming

Tags: c, networking, file-transfer

for some reason, it's not transferring content over. I had strlen(file) in the send() function and it was working for txt file. It won't work with bin files though, so I changed it to bytes_read. Now nothing's transferring properly. I'm getting blank files on the client side. Also, in debugging with print statements, I noticed the bin file is skipping the read() while loop. Any ideas?

Here's my client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "packetErrorSend.h"
#include <sys/time.h>
#define MAX_LINE 1000

ssize_t recvx(int sockfd, void *buf, size_t len) {
  int var = recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
  if(var != -1)
  {
    return var;
  } else {
    printf("%s \n","Did not receive.");
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char buf[MAX_LINE];
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *rp, *result;
  int bytes_received =  1;
  int s;
  char *server;
  char *port;
  char *file;
  int fd = -1; //file descriptor
  int bytes_written = 1;

  if (argc==4)
  {
    server = argv[1];
    port = argv[2];
    file = argv[3];
  }
  else
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid # of arguments\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Translate host name into peer's IP address */
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = 0;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;

  if ((s = getaddrinfo(server, port, &hints, &result)) != 0 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: getaddrinfo: %s\n", argv[0], gai_strerror(s));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Iterate through the address list and try to connect */
  for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
  {
    if ((s = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol)) == -1 )
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (connect(s, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
    {
      break;
    }
    close(s);
  }

  if (rp == NULL)
  {
    perror("stream-talk-client: connect");
    exit(1);
  }
  freeaddrinfo(result);

  /*send lines of text */
  send(s, file, sizeof(file)+30, 0);
  int status = recv(s,buf,1,0);

  if(status == 0 || buf[0] == 'e')
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: unable to access file %s \n", file);
    close(s);
    exit(0);
  }

  if(buf[0] == 's')
  {

    while(bytes_received != 0)
    {
      bytes_received = recvx(s, buf, 20);
      if(bytes_received == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Client Error: Error receiving file \n");
        exit(0);
      } else {
        if(fd == -1)
        {
          fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
          if(fd == -1)
          {
            fprintf(stderr,"Client Error: Open failed \n");
            break;
          }
          bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
          if(bytes_written == -1)
          {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
            break;
          }
        } else {
          bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
          if(bytes_written == -1)
          {
            fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(close(fd) != 0)
  {
    printf("%s \n", "Client Error: File did not close successfully");
    exit(0);
  }


  close(s);

  return 0;

}
```

Server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/sendfile.h>
#include "packetErrorSend.h"

#define SERVER_PORT "5432"
#define MAX_LINE 2000
#define MAX_PENDING 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct addrinfo hints;
  struct addrinfo *rp, *result;
  char file[MAX_LINE];
  int s, new_s;
  int bytes_transferred = 0;
  int fd; //file descriptor
  char status[1];
  int bytes_read = 0;

  /* Build address data structure */
  memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
  hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;
  hints.ai_protocol = 0;
  hints.ai_canonname = NULL;
  hints.ai_addr = NULL;
  hints.ai_next = NULL;

  /* Get local address info */
  if ((s = getaddrinfo(NULL, argv[1], &hints, &result)) != 0 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: getaddrinfo: %s\n", argv[0], gai_strerror(s));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Iterate through the address list and try to perform passive open */
  for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
  {
    if ((s = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol)) == -1 )
    {
      continue;
    }

    if (!bind(s, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen))
    {
      break;
    }
    close(s);
  }
  if (rp == NULL)
  {
    perror("stream-talk-server: bind");
    exit(1);
  }
  if (listen(s, MAX_PENDING) == -1)
  {
    perror("stream-talk-server: listen");
    close(s);
    exit(1);
  }

  freeaddrinfo(result);

  /* Wait for connection, then receive and print text */
  while(1)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(file); i++)
    {
      file[i] = '\0';
    }

    if ((new_s = accept(s, rp->ai_addr, &(rp->ai_addrlen))) < 0)
    {
      perror("stream-talk-server: accept");
      close(s);
      exit(0);
    }
    while(bytes_transferred == recv(new_s,file,sizeof(file),0))
    {
      if(bytes_transferred == -1)
      {
        close(new_s);
        exit(0);
      }
    }
    fd =open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
      status[0] = 'e';
      send(new_s,status,sizeof(status),0);
      close(new_s);
      exit(0);

    }
    else
    {
      status[0] = 's';
      send(new_s,status,sizeof(status),0);
      while(bytes_read == read(fd,file,sizeof(file)) > 0)
      {
        if(bytes_read < 0)
        {
          close(new_s);
          exit(0);
        }
      }

      while((bytes_transferred = send(new_s,file,bytes_read,0)) > 0)
      {
        if(bytes_transferred == -1)

        {
          close(new_s);
          exit(0);
        }
      }
      if(close(fd) != 0)
      {
        close(new_s);
        exit(0);
      }
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  close(new_s);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * file` ... `sizeof(file)+30` Perhaps before trying to send a file over the net, ask how to send a string properly.

Answer (score 1):

Usual copy loop problem:

```
while((bytes_transferred == send(new_s,file,sizeof(file),0)) > 0)
```

should be

```
while((bytes_transferred = send(new_s,file,bytes_read,0)) > 0)
```

Detailed commentary on your code:

```
send(s, file, sizeof(file)+30, 0);
```

should be

```
send(s, file, strlen(file)+1, 0);
```

Then:

```
while(bytes_received != 0)
{
  bytes_received = recvx(s, buf, 20);
  if(bytes_received == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Client Error: Error receiving file \n");
    exit(0);
  } else {
    if(fd == -1)
    {
      fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
      if(fd == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"Client Error: Open failed \n");
        break;
      }
      bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
      if(bytes_written == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
        break;
      }
    } else {
      bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
      if(bytes_written == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s \n", "Client Error: Write error");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A much simpler way to write all this would be:

```
fd = open(file, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if(fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Client Error: Open failed %s\n", strerror(errno));
   break;
}
while((bytes_received = recvx(s, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0)
{
      bytes_written = write(fd,buf,bytes_received);
      if(bytes_written == -1)
      {
        fprintf(stderr,"%s %s\n", "Client Error: Write error", strerr(errno));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
if(bytes_received == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Client Error: Error receiving file %s\n", strerr(errno));
    exit(0);
}
```

In the server, your code inside the accept loop is totally bizarre. It can be reduced to:

```
// receive a target file name
if ((bytes_transferred = recv(new_s,file,sizeof(file),0) > 0)
{
    fd = open(file,O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        perror("open");
        status[0] = 'e';
        send(new_s,status,1,0);
        close(new_s);
        exit(0);
    }
    status[0] = 's';
    send(new_s,status,1,0);

    while ((bytes_read = read(fd, file, sizeof file)) > 0)    
    {
        if (send(new_s,file,bytes_read,0) < 0)
        {
            perror("send");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bytes_transferred == 0)
    {
       break;
    }
    else if(bytes_transferred == -1)
    {
        perror("read");
        close(new_s);
        exit(0);
    }
}
close(new_s);
```

E&OE

Note that you don't have to length-check `send()` in blocking mode. Posix requires that it blocks until all data has been transferred.

Comment: I tried this once before and got stuck in an infinite loop(not sure why). Tucuxi had it right. Thanks for your response though

Comment: 'Tucuxi had it right' .. not remotely:(   strlen rarely fixes anything in network code.  Instead, it gives a false sense of security that lasts until you transfer some binary file with embedded NULs.  Then you're stuft:(

Comment: haha yeah you're right. All the tests pass until I transfer binary files. However, changing it to bytes_read, nothing transfers properly. The .txt files are blank and transferring the .bin files causes it to skip the read() while loop and still sends over 0 bytes which yields a blank file.

Comment: Did you observe the `==` to `=` fix?

Comment: I didn't at first, changed it. No difference in behavior though.

Comment: Your server code makes absolutely no sense, and your client code needs work too. See edit.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Yeah i was sure I did things the long way, that's how I logically piece things together. Get it working and then simplify it later. Thank you very much for this. I'll look through the edits and piece it together. Might just be a logic flaw on my part.

Comment: Woo everything's working. Had to make a few adjustments based on variables (i.e. bytes_read == bytes_transferred), but other than that, it works. It was a flaw in my logic somewhere when I tried to complicate things

Comment: @MartinJames I only pointed to an error and a possible (yes, text-only) fix. The fact that OP was using it for text (`MAX_LINE` instead of `MAX_BUFFER` strongly points to that) is why I went for the easy route. Good for you for fixing everything, but downvoting a valid improvement is overkill.

Comment: `send(s, file, strlen(file)+1, 0);` This is just as wrong as the original. The other side doesn't know the length.

Answer (score -2):

In your code, `sizeof(file)` is always `MAX_LINE`, hence the garbage at the end. Because `sizeof` cares nothing about what you put into variables; it only cares about their in-memory size:

```
#define MAX_LINE 2000
// ...
char file[MAX_LINE]; // sizeof(file) == 2000
```

Also, this line is writing beyond the length of the `file` array, and probably zeroing out some other variable that you care about:

```
file[sizeof(file)]='\0'; // very bad idea
```

To fix your initial problem, measure what your are sending (use `strlen`, or even better, `strnlen`) - and send only those bytes, including the terminating `'\0'` , instead of always sending `MAX_LEN`.

---

EDIT: after multiple downvotes, apparently due to not warning against the use of `strlen` & co. when used on non-textual inputs, I will now warn against the use of `strlen` for non-textual inputs:

- do not use `strlen` unless your input is 100% text.
- do not use it anyway, even with text: `strnlen` is safer, as it will never overflow the buffer (as long as the maximum-length parameter is correctly set):

  char line[MAX_LINE];
  // ... read into line somehow
  int line_length = strnlen(line, MAX_LINE-1);
  // make sure that it is 0-terminated
  line[line_length] = 0;

To send binary data, you need to measure it first. File sizes can be measured using [fseek and ftell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238607/15472). Do not try to use string functions (such as `strnlen`) or print (`printf`) binary data, as many bytes will map to control characters and mess up the display. If you need to print binary data, use code [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776146/15472).

Comment: sweet, that fixed my issue. I forgot about strlen function. Thanks for pointing out the other issues. I think file[sizeof(file)]='\0'; was there in trying to fix my problem, i thought it wasn't terminating at the end. Thanks for clearing up the differences in strlen and sizeof.

Comment: @Mike1982 please forget about it again:(

Comment: The measure of what's read is given by `bytes_read`, not by `strlen()`, unless you execute a lot of pointless extra code, and even then it fails unless the file is all text.

Comment: yeah i see what u mean. ran into another issue. I need to be able to transfer any type of file. It doesn't work with .bin files. It transfers, but it's a blank file. When I put print statements inside the while loop where I'm reading contents into the buffer, nothing prints out, so I'm assuming for some reason read is returning 0 and skipping that while loop. If I use bytes_read for the send (which makes sense), I get stuck in an infinite loop. Any idea what's going wrong now? I'll update current fixes above.

Comment: nvm, not stuck in a loop, it's just not transferring when using bytes_read for send. I had to add another condition to get it to stop.

Comment: Two downvotes, but no explanations on why those downvotes (unless it is my proposed use of `strlen`). Bad use of `sizeof` was certainly causing trouble. I feel unjustly downvoted

Comment: @EJP naming a constant "MAX_LINE" certainly seems to imply that you intend to use it to put textual lines in. Generally speaking, text is easier than binary, and OP is clearly learning about C. My answer concentrates on misuse of `sizeof`; I believe (as confirmed by OP) that it was causing extra garbage to be sent. I have not attempted to fix all problems with the code, just the most glaring.