# Treating an unsigned int address as a pointer and dereferencing it as a byte array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, byte, memory-address

So, I have an `unsigned int` variable with a decimal value address stored on it, let's say `unsigned int var = 1232342`, what I am trying to do is, without knowing the type of the variable **but** knowing the size of it and the address where it is stored, get the values as a `byte array`. For example, let's say I have an `int var = 20` with its address and bytesize. I want to be able to go to that address and return a byte array, in this case `[00001100]` and the same for `char` variables and data members of a struct.

A little bit of pseudocode would be something like:

```
for var.address until var.address = var.address + bytesize
    do 
       byte_array = *var.address
       var.address++
```

I am encountering some problems though, I am kind of new to C so I don't know how to treat an unsigned int as an address/pointer. Second, I don't know how to get the actual bytes out of the address, whenever I dereference the address what I get is the actual value of it, but that is if I know the type for the variable.

**A little bit of background:** *I am working on a tool called Pin which gives me the option to hook into a running process, then I am using the DWARF and ELF info. So I do have access to the virtual memory space I am trying to access*

Comment: `some_byte = *(unsigned char*)(address + offset)`

Comment: this gives me a segmentation fault @AusCBloke

Comment: this is not always `[00001100]`. Endianness!!!

Comment: @attis: You're probably trying to dereference an invalid address, or an `unsigned int` might not be large enough to hold the address of a valid pointer.

Answer (score 1):

"a" is the address from where you want to get 4 bytes. "bytes" is where you want to store your results. I assigned the address of "i" to "a", then read 4 bytes from that address.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    int i = 65535, j;
    unsigned long a = (unsigned long) &i;

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        bytes[j] = *((unsigned char*) a + j);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        printf("bytes[%d]: %d\n", j, bytes[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `hexdump` function by [epatel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842/epatel) here

[Off-the-Shelf C++ Hex Dump Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242/off-the-shelf-c-hex-dump-code)

In spite of the title it's really C code.  I'll copy it here for your convenience

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void hexdump(void *ptr, int buflen) {
  unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)ptr;
  int i, j;
  for (i=0; i<buflen; i+=16) {
    printf("%06x: ", i);
    for (j=0; j<16; j++) 
      if (i+j < buflen)
        printf("%02x ", buf[i+j]);
      else
        printf("   ");
    printf(" ");
    for (j=0; j<16; j++) 
      if (i+j < buflen)
        printf("%c", isprint(buf[i+j]) ? buf[i+j] : '.');
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```